# How do you accept your own edit proposals after receiving edit privilege?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits

I just got the edit privilege (hooray!), and just minutes before I proposed an edit on a question. Now when I try to accept the proposed edit to the question with my new superpowers, I get the message:

> Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because:
>   You seem to be improving a post however, you made no changes.

So, how can I accept/edit this question with the edits I proposed earlier?

I also see this on top of the question:

> Thanks for your edit!
>   This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed.

Which basically should mean I could accept the edit, right?

---

EDIT: Just found out I don't have review-privileges, see my [other relevant question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119848/edit-privileges-but-not-review-edit-privileges) please.

Comment: It's probably best to just let that post get cleared out by others.

Comment: But it's still a bug, right?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/184746)! Just for fun, you can try approving it from here (unless someone has gotten to it) :)

Comment: I don't see a button to approve it with, but thanks for the link! Cool to see my edit-statistics :)

Comment: [status-by-design].  Peer review means review by a peer, not review by yourself, and you suggested the edit when you had insufficient privileges to perform a direct edit.

Comment: I should be able to edit it after getting the edit privileges though, don't you think?

Comment: Heh, fun, you don't get too many chances to catch this in action. :) Probably not a large enough inconvenience to actually change software though.

Comment: @Emil But you already had a *pending* edit, so no; I don't think you should be able to edit it until the pending edit is approved or rejected.

Comment: If this question is about Stack Overflow, then two users require to approve a suggested edit, and those two users are not who suggested the edit. This is similar to approving tag wiki edit; who suggested the edit cannot approve it.

Comment: @AndrewBarber He's wondering why he can't approve his own pending edit after he gains edit privileges when if he had not made that pending edit just before gaining the privilege, it wouldn't need approval.  If he now has edit privileges, why can't he approve his own edits?  Even if his peers reject it, he can just make the actual edit anyway without their approval.  (Ignoring rollbacks)

Comment: @Troyen I know what he's asking. It still stands: "Peer Review" is not "Self Review". The use case of a potential change here is tiny. It's not worth introducing an inconsistency, IMO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to think of that edit prior to any change in your reputation. At the time you submitted that edit, you were considered "not trusted" to make full edits on your own without approval. Once you pass the threshold, you are now considered "trusted" and all future edits will be made instantaneous. But, you can't go back and approve everything you've done before because you made those edits in the "not trusted" state. That's like passing a law and then arresting someone for breaking that law prior to it existing. Your privilege, as with a new law, only applies to things done after the privilege is gained.

While I understand where you're coming from, this is definitely not a major issue that a lot of people care about. If for some reason you are needing to edit that same post again already after gaining full edit privileges, then perhaps your original edit that was suggested wasn't a very sufficient one. However, I like thinking of ideas.

**Ideas:**

- If they really want too, I'm sure they could build a small script that, when a user gains full edit privileges, would go through all their still pending suggested edits and automatically approve them through the Community user. Community already approves tons of other things on its own.
- Allow users to withdraw a suggested edit. Rather than showing the normal Approve, Reject, and Improve buttons, display a Withdraw button that will in effect reject their own suggested edit, allowing the user to make a new, alternate edit.

Comment: I think the withdrawing is too much complexity for such a corner case, but the Community-approval sounds reasonable. The system already keeps track of which privileges a user earns as evidenced by the notification banner.