# Edit privileges but not review-edit privileges?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I just got the Edit-privilege on SO, and in the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) it says:

> 2000 - Edit other people’s posts, vote to approve or reject suggested edits

However, when I try to access the review-page for suggested edits (https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/), I just get a message saying

> The page you're trying to visit requires the privilege “approve tag wiki edits.”
>   You receive additional privileges on Stack Overflow by earning more reputation through participation on the site. When you have earned at least 5000 reputation, you will receive the “approve tag wiki edits” privilege and will be allowed to view this page.

So it seems I should not be able to review edits after all, although that is what the FAQ says. Is it a bug in the system or an error in the FAQ? Either way, I think it seems pointless being able to edit posts but not see suggested edits as well as being able to accept/decline/improve them.

I am tagging this as a bug, feel free to retag if you disagree.

Comment: It's definitely not a bug. The reputation requirement to access the queue used to be 10k and was lowered to 5k at some point. As Dennis said, you *can* review suggested edits if you stumble upon them.

Comment: Also, FWIW, there's an [API route for suggested edits](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/suggested-edits), even pending ones.

Comment: Seems strange not allowing users with Edit-privileges to see that page when the API is accessible to all, don't you think?

Comment: [Yes, I do](http://stackapps.com/questions/2830/api-v2-0-public-beta-begins#comment6981_2830).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You **can** vote to approve or reject a suggested edit. To do so, click on the `edit (N)` link below a question or an answer. If there is a pending edit (you can tell from the presence of the `(N)`), you can vote.

However, you **cannot** see the list of all suggested edits. That's something entirely different.

From [Privileges - Approve Tag Wiki Edits - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits):

> **Vote on suggested edits**
>
> In addition, users with this privilege level also get access to the suggested edits queue. The queue has a list of posts which have been edited upon by users who don't have edit privileges. This queue can be accessed over at the [suggested edits tab in the review section](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits).

Comment: Okay, I see. I guess I just never saw the `(N)` before. This should be specified in the "Edit privilege"-prilivege-page, though.

Comment: This answer appears to be outdated. 2k users should now be able to see the Suggested Edits queue (minus the tag wiki suggested edits). See [the 2k privilege page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) or e.g. [this meta.SO question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168220/how-are-suggested-edits-in-the-review-queue-to-be-handled).