# Edit waiting for approval, but >2k

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you accept your own edit proposals after receiving edit privilege?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119814/how-do-you-accept-your-own-edit-proposals-after-receiving-edit-privilege)

I made a suggested edit while I had less than 2k rep (but only barely) on a question That I answered which brought me over 2k.

I now still see that the edit has not been approved and is only visible to me. I am also shown the edit link, but not shown that there is an edit pending. I am unable to re-edit my edit to make it stick, even though I now have >2k.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I'm assuming it's this question: [C#: Referencing Classes by a Variable Syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827658/c-referencing-classes-by-a-variable-syntax)? Just voted to approve the edit.

Comment: [animuson has a great answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119814/how-do-you-accept-your-own-edit-proposals-after-receiving-edit-privilege/119821#119821) that approximates how we feel about this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a perfect world the system would auto-approve your suggested edit once you hit 2K, but in reality engineering that would take a fair amount of work, and is an *extremely* rare edge case.

There's no way the team is going to take time to fix this when there are [outstanding feature requests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106717/does-so-need-social-networking-features-to-improve-the-experience-for-expert-use) pending

Comment: Interesting "outstanding feature request pending" that you chose to link to. I don't think ones marked [meta-tag:status-declined] or those involving "social networking" features are ones really competing for the team's time.

Comment: @Cody - not usually, but this one was declined in the Atwood days, and is highly, highly supported by the community.  Only Pekka could request social networking features and not be run out of town.

Comment: Hmm yeah, it has gotten a fair number of upvotes. If that gets implemented, I'm going to miss Jeff more and more. The only redeeming quality about that feature request is that it is entirely opt-in. If I don't "recommend" stuff, people can't "follow" me. Anything more than that, and I concur with Jeff about being "violently opposed". Sometimes I wonder if I'm the only person on Meta who regularly upvoted his declination reasons.

Comment: @Cody, **nobody**, including me, would ever upvote *any* social networking features that weren't opt-in.  Pekka's request is great since, as he says in his bounty message, it helps people mine the site for the diamonds -- those few questions (and answers) which are truly stellar

Comment: I still think I agree with waffles: isn't that what upvotes are for? And I imagine it was the original idea behind the "favorites" feature, and could be again if some energy was focused on the other feature requests aimed at improving that.

Comment: @Cody - I actually have a feature request in for improving the favorites.  That would be great.  But Pekka's idea is for when, say, Eric Lippert or Jon Skeet answer a question that's actually quite smart.  Neither of them would have any use "Favoriting" the question, but it would be neat if they could click "recommend", and people who are "following" them would see the question show up in a feed.  (just those questions, not the millions of other questions they answer that are simple, that even *I* could answer)